# java / eclipse : recursion function , control entering both If and else condition

Tags: java, recursion

I need help in understanding this recursive function

```
 private int findFactorial(int n) {

        if (n == 0) { 
            return 1;
        } else {
            return (n * findFactorial(n - 1));
        }

    }
```

my question, when n==0 the function returns 1 then why the final return of the function is not 1 and its factorial. 
I tried break point. In the final run when n==0 it enters the "if" condition and "else" condition , how can control enter if and else

EDIT: The eclipse shows as if the control is entering both if/else. editing because it is causing confusion to reader and my primary question was related to recursion and not why eclipse show such wired behavior

Comment: "How can control enter if and else?" => It cannot. Please show us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: At the final run, the method returns. Where does it return? Who called it? Think carefully. What happens when you call the method from the `findfactorial(n - 1)`? Where does the value of `findFactorial(n-1)` go?

Comment: It is not possible for value n control goes both if and else block

Comment: i know its not possible, but that is how eclipse is showing and confusing . Anyways I am going to carefully follow @RealSkeptic 's points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case n = 2 :**

- it goes to the else statement and there the value is **(2 * factorial(1))**
  so we have **2 * (something coming up)**.

**Now n = 1**

- it goes to the else statement again an the value is which we had before
  i.e. **2 * 1 * factorial (1-1)**

**NOW n = 0**

- Yes. This time it **goes to the if statement and returns 1**, which is returned to the previous else statement where **2 * 1 * ? is waiting for factorial(1-1).**
  So we get **2 * 1 * 1 = 2.**

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. it makes sense now. regards.

I tried visualizing like this 
n=4

f(4*f(3)) - > f(4*(f(3*(2))) - > f(4*(f(3*(f(2*(1))))) -> f(4*(f(3*(f(2*(f(1*(0))))))
f(1*(0)) - will return 1 , move from innermost to outer.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably misinterpreting what the debugger is telling you.  When `n` is zero you will execute the if branch.  After the `return 1`, the next thing that will be executed is the rest of the else branch *in the enclosing call to `findFactorial`*.  Check it again.

(You do not / should not / will will not get both the "if" and "else" branch executing in the same `findFactorial` call.  If somehow it did, that would be an Eclipse bug.)

Comment: yes,looks like eclipse bug. its stepping both if and else in the same call.